# what is the best practice for REST system design, ALB VS API gateway?

Tags: amazon-web-services, caching, amazon-elb

I am designing a "simple" RESTful API and in dilemma between the tow following designs:

[image]

**Top design:**

1. user send request to api getway which authenticate with cognito
2. api getway redirect to ALB that redirect to the ecs.
3. in case of a "CACHE" end point, the user would be redirect to lambda that would extract and return the data

**bottom design**

user request is authenticated by the ALB and move forward to the app, the app extract from cache.

My questions:

1. is the API gateway and lambda necessary? should I except a greater latency in the bottom?
2. An advantage I see at the top design is that i am able to distinguish between sync and async request, is it a good practice?
3. i learn recently that ALB can make the authentication to cognito  , can it also make authorisation to an endpoint?(check if a user belongs to a group that allow to access this endpoint)
4. More general, I am trying to get the best design to avoid latency, I have an endpoint that doesnot need to get live data and can relay on cashe.

thx in advance!